# why can't a 2-3 tree "allow" degree 1

Tags: data-structures, tree, binary-tree

A question I've been struggling with... 
Why the implementation of a 2-3 trees doesn’t allow nodes to have degree of 1?

I thought it might be related to the O(log(n)) it (as a member of the B tree family) wants to keep, if degree 1 was allowed we could get a tree like that:

```css
1
 \
  2
   \
    3
     \
      4
       \
        5
```

for example and then some operations will take O(n) instead of O(log(n))
but i don't see where in this answer i referred to a 2-3 tree and why it can't allow degree 1... :-/

thanks! ;-)

Comment: In principle you could allow a number of degree-1 nodes bounded by a constant (or even bounded by O(log n)) and not lose the asymptotic logarithmic depth. But 2-3 trees, well, don't.

Answer (score 0):

You already have the right answer, but maybe you want to say it like this:

> B-tree variants maintain all leaves at the same depth (the tree
>   height), and operations generally take time proportional to that
>   height.
>
> Since internal nodes must have at least 2 children, each
>   level contains at least twice as many nodes as the parent level, and
>   the height of the tree is O(log N).
>
> If internal nodes were allowed to contain
>   less than 2 children, the height could be more than O(log N) and
>   operations would take longer than logarithmic time.